# I'm trying to get the information inside ng-repeat to submit the form but fail

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post, laravel

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="AttCtrl">

        <div ng-repeat="type in types">
            <h5>@{{type.name}}</h5>
            <input type="hidden" name="@{{'type_'+$index}}" value="@{{type.name}}">
            <div ng-repeat="att in type.data">
                <a><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="delete(type.name,att)"></i></a> @{{att}} <br>
                <input type="hidden" name="@{{'att_'+$parent.$index+$index}}" value="@{{att}}">
            </div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="new_att" ng-enter="add_att(type.name,new_att); new_att='';">
            <a><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" ng-click="add_att(type.name,new_att); new_att='';"></i></a>
            <br><br>
        </div>

        <a ng-click="add_type()">new property</a>

        <hr>

    </div>
```

Everything seems to be okay. I can add and remove everything on the fly but when I submit, nothing inside ng-repeat is stored (the rest is okay).

**Laravel Controller**

```
        //@store
        $product = new Product;
        //a lot of stuff here
        $product->save();

        for ($i=0; Input::has('type_'.$i); $i++) { 
            for ($j=0; Input::has('att_'.$i.$j); $j++) { 
                $att = new Attribute;
                $att->name = Input::get('att_'.$i.$j);
                $att->type = Input::get('type_'.$i);
                $att->product_id = $product->id;
                $att->save();
            }
        }
```

thank in advance. :D

Comment: You data is being stored in DB but it is not reflecting in view?

Comment: There are other stuffs in the form and they are stored in DB except this part which is inside ng-repeat. Angular model works well.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-repeat creates a new scope for each repetition of it, so if you want to store the data correctly you need to point to the $parent scope so the data is stored in your controllers scope.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the cause because all I do is using ng-repeat to define each input tag a name and value. And then I use normal post request by clicking submit. I didn't use ajax at all. Which means I didn't try to use those new scope inside ng-repeat in .js file.

Am I understand you correctly, or I miss something?

Comment: Is it possible to get a plunkr of it? Also what does ng-enter do? it's not a angular directive.

Comment: ng-enter do the function when press return.